# Can a subform be outside parent form?

Tags: forms, ms-access

i.e. though parent form and subform are detached but function normally as they do.

Answer (score 3):

No. They are two independent forms. No way to utilize Master/Child Links properties available with a subform container control. Would require code (macro or VBA) to pass primary key value to either filter related child records or create new child record.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, subform as the name implies is a sub of another form, so its meant to be inside another form(its parent/main form)